# How can I manipuate each item in a list when using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-filter

The special variable `ansible_role_names` contains a list with roles names in my play. For example

```
"ansible_role_names": [
    "geerlingguy.nfs", 
    "ANXS.openssh", 
    "robertdebock.bootstrap", 
    "robertdebock.squid"
]
```

However what I want to access is this list with everything before the dot removed.

```
"roles": [
    "nfs", 
    "openssh", 
    "bootstrap", 
    "squid"    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q: *"How to manipulate each item in an array when using Ansible?"*

A: It's possible to *`map`* the [*regex_replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) filter. For example the play

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ ansible_role_names|
                 map('regex_replace', regex, replace)|
                 list }}"
  vars:
    regex: '^(.*)\.(.*)$'
    replace: '\2'
- debug:
    var: my_list
```

gives

```
"my_list": [
    "nfs", 
    "openssh", 
    "bootstrap", 
    "squid"
]
```

---

`regex: '^(.*)\.(.*)$'`

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `(.*)` matches any character in capture group No.1
- `\.` matches `.`
- `(.*)` matches any character in capture group No.2
- `$` matches the end of the string

`replace: '\2'`

- `\2` matches previously defined capture group No.2

Comment: I just spend 4hours to find a solution to the same problem. Never heard of the regex+replace args. This solved my issue too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Building-up on @Arbab Nazar answer: splitting the strings on dots and using index `1` on the resulting list might break on some occasions.

- If your role name does not contain a dot (pretty common for local roles), you will get an error with an undefined variable => `list object has no element 1`
- In the (unlikely...) case your role has several dots in its name, you will always get the second element in the string, not the last

Using `-1` as the index (e.g. first element starting from the end) will fix both of those potential problems like in the following example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split('.')[-1] }}"
  loop:
    - simplerole
    - classic.galaxyrole
    - non.standard.customrole
```

Which gives the following result:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=simplerole) => {
    "msg": "simplerole"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=classic.galaxyrole) => {
    "msg": "galaxyrole"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=non.standard.customrole) => {
    "msg": "customrole"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by using the `split` filter:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split('.')[-1] }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_role_names }}"
```